# Turning a Variable into a Function? (Code works, interesting behavior)

Tags: python, function, variables, behavior

I am currently working on a project that involves reading a single character from the command-line without waiting for newlines. I found a helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/2844655), and followed it to its source [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/). I modified the code slightly, and now I have the following:

```
import sys,tty,termios
class _Getch:       
    def __call__(self):
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch

def main():
    inkey = _Getch()
    while(1):
        k=inkey()
        if k!='':break
    print 'you pressed', k
```

The part that is interesting to me here is the **`inkey()`**. I have tried modifying it to `k=inkey` or `k=_Getch`, etc. but then it doesn't work as it is meant to. As far as I can tell, no `inkey()` method had been defined previously, so it seems like the variable `inkey=_Getch()` is somehow being used as a function.

I don't understand what's going on here. How is this possible? What is the underlying mechanic that is being used? I'd be glad if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Getch` is a class, and `inkey` is an instance of the class. It is not a function.

```
class A:
    pass

a = A() # instantiate an object of class A
```

You should definitely read the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).